# Monitor switch traffic load on specific port (CISCO managed switch)

Tags: networking, port, switch, traffic, network-monitoring

For troubleshooting networks problems I need to know how to monitor the traffic (work load) on a managed switch.

I read about SPAN for CISCO switches. But it seems to be overkill since it does mirror a port for further analyzing.

Then I know that there are SNMP commands to query certain switch information. This is probably a lot of manual work.

What i really need is just the traffic in mega-bit or percentage on a specific port on a cisco managed switch (WS-C2960S).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: look into a SNMP poller like Cacti or MRTG.

Answer (score 1):

This seems exactly what you need:

> show controllers utilization
>
> Use the show controllers utilization command in EXEC mode to display bandwidth utilization on the switch or specific ports.
>
> show controllers [interface-id] utilization

[(Taken from Catalyst 2960 reference quide)](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst2960/software/release/12-2_58_se/command/reference/2960cr/cli2.html#wp3573524)